# A specific exercise on intermediate value theorem

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

> Verifies that all functions of the form
>   $$f(x)=ax^5+bx^3+cx^2+d, \quad a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R, \quad a\neq 0 \tag 1$$
>   have at least a zero.

For my humble opinion I think that it is important to consider the particular cases: $b=0  \vee c=0 \vee d=0$.

- If $b=c=d=0$, the $(1)$ becomes $f(x)=ax^5$ that it has a zero (of multiplicity $5$) in the point $O(0,0)$.
- If $c=d=0$ and $b\ne 0$, I have  $f(x)=ax^5+bx^3$ where in the closed and limited $0\in[-2,2]$ interval we have $f(-2)\cdot f(2)<0$.
- If $d=0 \wedge b,c\neq 0$ we have $f(x)=ax^5+bx^3+cx^2=x^2(ax^3+bx+c)$ ans surely $f(x)=0 \iff x^2=0$.
  etc.

> Exist another simple proof to solve this exercise in a complete way?

Comment: @downvoter: is there a reason I should be voted negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how $f$ behaves as $x \to \infty$ and $x \to -\infty$; then use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for you answer. Can I ask you nicely, how would you solve this completely? Just to get an idea of another kind of solution. Thank you.